How to push remote code in vs-editor to github repository?
When I try to add my remote code to github using :
git remote add origin https://github.com/alfred-nrml/IMdb-Database-Website.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
It shows errors like this
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/alfred-nrml/IMdb-Database-Website.git'
I searched across the internet to solve this issue , it shows like rename master branch to main branch but in this case I have only empty repo in my github where I want to link my code which is in vscode remotely ...

Does the repository have a branch named main? Is it maybe master instead?

Your error is not "failed to push some refs", your error is "src refspec main does not match any". Do you have the branch main? Have you added and committed anything? Show us the text output of git branch and git status

The branch is main here . It shows changes not stagged for commit .

So first you have initialized a git repo and then you have connected the local repo to the remote repo located in your GitHub account by using
git remote add origin https://github.com/alfred-nrml/IMdb-Database-Website.git

then you have changed your default branch from master to main by using
git branch -M main

then after working when you have seen your git status for first time then it shows files in red colour:

After that you have staged all the files by using
[git add .] or [git add -A] or [git add *] or [git add -all]

and then you have see the status again in which all files are in green colour:

Now comes the problem, after staging the files, you first have to commit the files and not directly push.
So this time after staging you first make the commit by using the following command
git commit -m "message"

in the place of message in "message", you can put any message like "index.html added" or "package.json modified" etc to express about what you have done
After this step, now if you push the repo it would be done successfully
